# vb.net login access control

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms

im making a mysql sigin form and im trying to use my user table to control log in access but whenever i type in any random letters it logs into without showing the error that its an invalid username.

This is what i have so far:

```
   Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

    Public Class frmLogin
        Private Sub cmdCancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdCancel.Click
            Application.Exit()
        End Sub

        Private Sub cmdLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdLogin.Click
            Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
            Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand

            Dim myConnString As String
            Dim UserID As String

            myConnString = "server=" & My.Settings.HostIP & ";" _
                & "user id=" & My.Settings.Username & ";" _
                & "password=" & My.Settings.Password & ";" _
                & "database=attendance"

            conn.ConnectionString = myConnString

            Try
                conn.Open()

                myCommand.Connection = conn
                myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT user_bannerid FROM user WHERE BINARY username = ?Username"
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("?Username", txtUsername.Text)

                UserID = myCommand.ExecuteScalar

                conn.Close()

                Dim mainForm As New frmMain
                mainForm.UserID = UserID
                mainForm.connectionString = myConnString
                mainForm.Show()

                Me.Hide()
                Me.Close()
            Catch myerror As MySqlException
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid User. Please Enter Your Correct Username")
                conn.Dispose()
            End Try
        End Sub

        Private Sub frmLogin_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Me.AcceptButton = cmdLogin
            Me.CancelButton = cmdCancel
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are not testing the value of userid before closing the form.

You also need to implement using statements to ensure that all disposable items are properly disposed.

Here is a rewrite that solves both issues:

```
    Try
        Using conn As New MySqlConnection
            Using myCommand As New MySqlCommand
                Dim myConnString As String
                Dim UserID As String

                myConnString = "server=" & My.Settings.HostIP & ";" _
                    & "user id=" & My.Settings.Username & ";" _
                    & "password=" & My.Settings.Password & ";" _
                    & "database=attendance"

                conn.ConnectionString = myConnString

                conn.Open()

                myCommand.Connection = conn
                myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT user_bannerid FROM user WHERE BINARY username = ?Username"
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("?Username", txtUsername.Text)

                Dim oUserID As Object

                oUserID = myCommand.ExecuteScalar

                conn.Close()

                If oUserID IsNot DBNull.Value AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(oUserID) Then
                    Dim mainForm As New frmMain
                    mainForm.UserID = UserID
                    mainForm.connectionString = myConnString
                    mainForm.Show()

                    Me.Hide()
                    Me.Close()
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid User. Please Enter Your Correct Username")
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("SQL Error" & myerror.ToString())
    End Try
```